# Should my Activity have menu as well as Action bar icons?

Tags: android

I am developing an application of my own and was reading this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

It says:

> Beginning with Android 3.0, the Menu button is deprecated (some
>   devices don't have one), so you should migrate toward using the action
>   bar to provide access to actions and other options.

My app is only targeting android 4.2+. Does that mean I should present the menu options as only action bar icons ? What if there is not enough room available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items that do not fit in the action bar will automatically be relegated to the overflow menu. All you have to do is set the  `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` property in your xml for the menu item.

This basically tells the system that this menu item should be displayed as an action icon if there is room available. If not, it should be shown as an overflow menu item.

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is no more hardware Menu Button. Your menu items will be showed in popup under "three-doted icon". In menu.xml you can configure everything:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_example"
        android:title="@string/action_example"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" /> <!-- attention -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

[Read more here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)

If you need a lot of icons to be showed you can split ActionBar(second(bottom) menu bar will appear).
[documantation of splitting](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)

I hope mine explanation will be good enough:)